# Angularjs count ng-show ocurrences in markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a ng-repeat with several filters and a ng-show validation that shows an indicator (badge) within the ng-repeat:

```
ng-show="(item.localDate | amDifference : lastRefreshDate : 'minutes')>=-15 && !item.state"
```

I need to count how many of this validations are true. I know that one can loop through the array before and count the ocurrences in the controller, but is there a way to do it directly in the markup as the ng-repeat is already doing the loop?

**UPDATE**

I tried using:

```
ng-init="total = (item.localDate | amDifference : lastRefreshDate : 'minutes')>=-15 && !item.state ? total+1 : total"
```

Which didn't work.

Also tried a function in the controller:

```
$scope.iter = function(item) {
  var localDate = moment(item.localDate);
  var diff = localDate.diff(angular.copy($scope.lastRefreshDate), 'minutes');
  if (diff >= -15 && item.state === 0) {
    $scope.newFeeds += 1;
  }
};
```

Calling it like this in the template:

```
{{iter(item))}}
```

But it makes the app loop until it crashes.

I tried creating a Directive, but I struggle assigning the value to the parent scope whilst also passing the variables from the template.

If I do manually another for loop, it "works" but the view updates after the 15 minutes validation, but my counter doesn't.

I have to add that I am using Ionic Framework.

Comment: did you already thought about using directives?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes its an option, but i was thinking on something like ng-init (which was an answer and seems got deleted..) I'm testing it otherwise a directive it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
ng-init="iter(item)"
```

in the ng-repeat statement.

calling to:

```
$scope.iter = function(item) {
  var localDate = moment(item.localDate);
  var diff = localDate.diff(angular.copy($scope.lastRefreshDate), 'minutes');
  if (diff >= -15 && item.state === 0) {
    $scope.newFeeds += 1;
  }
};
```